# Erro ao executar projeto no TomCat

Tags: java, aplicação-web, java-ee, tomcat

Olá pessoal estou tentando executar um projeto JavaWeb no TomCat, porém quando executo ele dá esse erro:

> **HTTP Status 404 - /Drogaria/faces/templates/modeloSistema.xhtml** 
>       **type Status report**
>
> **message /Drogaria/faces/templates/modeloSistema.xhtml**
>
> **description The requested resource is not available.**
>
> **Apache Tomcat/7.0.82**

Em outros projetos executo e roda normal , só este que está com problemas, o servidor está configurado certinho, está estartado, e sincronizado.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Drogaria</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <p:layout fullPage="true">
  <p:layoutUnit position="north">
  </p:layoutUnit>
  
  <p:layoutUnit position="center">
  </p:layoutUnit>
 </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posta a estrutura do projeto por favor

Comment: Posta seu faces.config e web.xml